# Dictionary keys and strings

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm just getting started with dictionaries in python and I got stumbled at the following code snippet:

```
for word in word_dict:
    print(word) # Obviously returns the key
print("draw" in word_dict) # returns False even though the key is existent
```

I suppose the `False` is returned maybe due to the incompatibility of types like `"draw"` is a string and `word` in the loop is a `some sort of string key type` maybe.

But when I inspect the types I can see both are `<class 'str'>` type only !!

How do I convert the string key I provide like "draw" to be acceptable as a key and it returns True? I guess this is a simple oversight but I need to know what the problem here is !

Comment: What is the output of `word_dict.keys()`?

Comment: Thanks @schwobaseggl you are right. The keys had newline character at the end. Thats the reason I get False when I give a string manually. You can give it as an answer below.

Comment: That's ok. I will vote to close this as not reproducible.

Comment: Thanks, I actually want to delete this post as it was a personal oversight, which I couldn't do as you guys answered this.

Comment: That's a good idea ;)

Comment: I couldn't delete as other's posted their answers :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your time into this.

I actually split the words in a file to keys in the dictionary and while doing so the keys also had a trailing `\n`. That's the reason I get False when I give a string without newline. I found this out when I inspected by looping through keys of `word_dict.keys()`

Thanks to [schwobaseggl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2390182/schwobaseggl) for leading me into the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are kinda lost here.

`for variable in dict_var:` - iterates over `dict` keys

`dict.get(<key_name>)` return value for key `<key_name>`

```
for word in word_dict:
    print(word_dict.get(word))
```

Will return all values of your `dict`, since you iteration over all of its keys.

`some_var in word_dict` - checks if value of `some_var` in list of `word_dict` keys, so `print("draw" in word_dict)` just print `True`/`False` if key exist in your `dict`.

And i would **strongly** advise you to read docs on [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Comment: Thanks but actually I put word_dict.get(word) just to check it doesn't return None but the default value that I set to 0. Sorry for not mentioning it in the question.

Comment: @socket_var there is no sense in `word_dict.get(word)` because you iteration over `word_dict` keys, and that key would definitely exist.

Comment: Yes I'm sorry for the ambiguity. I was just checking whether I would get o the default value or None. I would keep your point in mind and check for key from here on. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure "draw" is one of the key of word_dict? check your dictionary.

```
    >>> word_dict = {"draw":1,"xx":2}
    >>> print ("draw" in word_dict)
    True
    >>>
```